# Change the value of some fileds in a file depending oon the value of the column

Tags: unix, awk, syntax, ksh

I have a file delimited by commas that has around 50 columns and can reach to 1M lines.

I want to evaluate if, for every line, certain columns, like 5, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49 and 50 have the values of Y|N|N/A, if not, it will replace for another value like E.
Im using awk for the process:

```
okfile="okfile"
awk -F, -v okfile="$okfile" '
  BEGIN {system("rm -f " okfile) }
  length > 0 {
     if (toupper($5) !~ /YES|NO|N\/A/ ) { $5="E",$0 >> okfile;numerr+=1;next }

     for (i=41;i<=50;i++)
        {  if (toupper($i) !~ /YES|NO|N\/A/)
           {
             $i="E",$0 >> okfile
             numerr+=1
             next
           }
        }
    }
 END {print numerr,"errors"}
' FILETOREAD.txt
```

This is always giving me syntax error and im not being able to solve it:

```
syntax error The source line is 5.
The error context is
       if_(toupper($5) !~ /YES|NO|N\/A/ { >>> {$5="E", <<<
awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
The source line is 5.
```

Anyone can help me?

Edited line 5, had a typo error in the end, had a ) instead of a }

Comment: What is `$5="E",$0 >> okfile` supposed to do? `BEGIN {system("rm -f " okfile) }` is a bad idea, btw, as it's referncing the contents of `okfile` unquoted. Just do it in shell before you call awk anyway - there's no reason to have a shell call awk to call system to spawn a shell to remove a file.

Comment: are you missing a curly and/or parent here? ```if (toupper($5) !~ /YES|NO|N\/A/ } { $5="E",$0 >> okfile;numerr+=1;next)```
Really hard to follow your indentation...

Comment: Is looks like the `)` and the`}` needs to be swapped.... in line 5.

Comment: @Ed Morton, with thge $5 = "E", $0 >> okfile i intend to change the column 5 for that line from what value it has to the value E, and then pick in the line and send it to okfile

Comment: @vgersh99 was a typo error, already put it right.

Comment: Even if this works you're capturing only the first error, isn't it better to mark them all in one pass?

Comment: @NunoMouro idk where you got the idea for that syntax from but it sounds like you were trying to do `$5 = "E"; print $0 >> okfile` (not saying that's the right thing to do, just that it's the right syntax for what I think you were trying to do). Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encapsulate the duplicated code into a function:

```
#!awk

  function is_err(field) {
    if (toupper($field) ~ /YES|NO|N\/A/)
      return 0   # not an error
    $field = "E"
    print > okfile
    numerr++
    return 1
  }

  length {
    if (is_err(5)) next
    for (i=41; i<=50; i++) if (is_err(i)) next
  }
  END {print numerr,"errors"}
```

Be aware when you reassign the value of a field, awk will regenerate $0 using OFS, so the lines going into $okfile will be **space-separated** not comma-separated.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this might be what you're trying to do (untested):

```
okfile="okfile"
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS=OFS=","
        flds[++numFlds] = 5
        for (i=41; i<=50; i++) {
            flds[++numFlds] = i
        }
    }
    NF {
        for ( n=1; n<=numFlds; n++ ) {
            i = flds[n]
            if ( toupper($i) !~ /^(YES|NO|N\/A)$/ ) {
                $j = "E"
                numerr++
            }
        }
        print
    }
    END { print numerr+0, "errors" | "cat>&2" }
' FILETOREAD.txt  > "$okfile"
```